# "Недопустимое имя столбца" в sql запросе windowsforms c#

Tags: c#

Создал форму и бд, подключил, но при добавлении вылезает ошибка, но цифры и числа добавляет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Текстовую информацию нужно здесь вставлять текстом

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка заключается в том , что когда вы вписываете в запрос Текстовое поле перед ним и в конце необходимо ставить кавычки ' '.
Вот так будет выглядеть верно ваш запрос.

```
cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO student(fio,age,fuculty,yearr) VALUES('{textBox1.Text}',{textBox2.Text},'{textBox3.Text}',{textBox4.Text});";
```

Ответ более развернуто: Если вы добавляете текстовое поле где нет пробелов то можно не ставить ' ' Но если вы добавите текст 'Привет я Вова' то тут обязательны кавычки, будет синтаксическая ошибка. И на будущее везде тип стринг обвертывайте в кавычки одинарные.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!